# How to include variables from one page in another when writing a file with fwrite()?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, fwrite

Here's the code:

```
<?php
// For use in creating individual page
$tpl_file = "submission.php";
$tpl_path = "templates/";
$submissions_path = "submissions/";



// For use in querying submitter name

$username = $_GET['username'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username; 

//Database Information

$dbhost = "";
$dbname = "";
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "";

//Connect to database

mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());


$name = $_POST['name'];
$filename = $_POST['filename'];   
$submitter = $username;
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("$filename");
$type = exif_imagetype($_POST['filename']);

$checkuser = mysql_query("SELECT filename FROM images WHERE filename='$filename'");

$filename_exist = mysql_num_rows($checkuser);

if($filename_exist > 0){
    echo "I'm sorry but this image has already been submitted. Please feel free to try another.";
    unset($filename);
    include 'upload.php';
    exit();
}


if (exif_imagetype($_POST['filename']) == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    echo "Sorry, but we can't accept GIFs. Please feel free to try uploading another.";
    unset($filename);
    include 'upload.php';
    exit();
}



$query = "INSERT INTO images (name, filename, submitter, width, height, type)
VALUES('$name', '$filename', '$submitter', '$width', '$height', $type)";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();

echo "Thanks for your submission!<br/> Upload another <a href='/~lyons/upload.php'>here</a>!";

$tpl = file_get_contents($tpl_path.$tpl_file);
$php_file_name = $name.".php";

$fh = fopen($submissions_path.$php_file_name, "w");
fwrite($fh, $tpl);
fclose($fp); 
?>
```

When a user submits a picture, it is supposed to automatically create a page based on a template. Here's the code for the template:

```
<html>
<title><?php echo $name; ?></title>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<h1><?php echo $name ?></h1>
Posted by: <?php echo $username ?>
<br/>
<img src="<?php echo $filename ?>"/>

</body>
</html>
```

As you might have already guessed, I want it to put in values for name, username, and filename that were derived in the first script where they submit the picture. However, it seems they don't carry over. The page is created, but where ever it's supposed to echo  the values for the variables, it is blank. **How can I include the values for those variables that I want to use in the created page?**

Thanks in advance to whoever can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a string like `%name%`, `%username%` etc. to mark placeholders for variables.

Then, before writing to the file, try something like this:

```
$tpl = preg_replace("(%([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)%)ie",'$$1',$tpl);
```

This will find, for example, `%filename%` and replace it with the contents of the variable `$filename`.

Comment: Do you suggest I just change the $tpl variable to that? Because I don't understand any of that code. Not your fault, I'm still learning.

Comment: In the template file, replace all your little PHP snippets with the `%varname%` form I suggested. Then add that line of code just before the `fwrite()` call. It should work just fine from there.

Comment: I suppose I'm doing this wrong then. In the template file, I put `<?php echo %name%; ?>` where I wanted the $name variable to display. Then, I replaced the value I had for the $tpl variable with what you gave me. The file isn't showing any of the template anymore, so where did I go wrong? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Okay, let's take this one step at a time. You shouldn't have replaced anything in the big code file, only added that line. Undo any changes you made to the code file (NOT the template file, leave that as it is now), then add the code line somewhere after defining `$tpl`, but before writing the file, and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, I added it right after the first value for $tpl, so now I have two values for $tpl: `$tpl = file_get_contents($tpl_path.$tpl_file);
$tpl = preg_replace("(%([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)%)ie",'$$1',$tpl);` I left everything else as is, including the template file, and now I'm back to nothing filled in for the variables. Sorry if I'm a bit hard to deal with, I've only been learning PHP for the past few weeks so I'm still quite novice.

Answer (score 0):

Look up PHP [Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

It is a built-in feature to PHP used for exactly what you're doing.

Sessions store data on a per-user basis however, so if you're wanting other people to see the variables, you're going to have to use either a database or saving to a file.

Comment: I think I sort of understand Sessions, but wouldn't that be more for showing that someone's logged in or something? If they go and submit another picture, what would happen to the data from the previous picture?

Comment: I guess i misunderstood what kind of information you want to store. You should use a database for storing paths to uploaded pictures and their uploaders.

Comment: I do, I just need a way to make the template file input the correct details for the individual submission. If I can't carry any variables over, then I can't tell it what I want it to take from the database.